# mysql BETWEEN date range not working

Tags: mysql

I have a table called `barcode_log`, and these are all the datas from the table.

[image: All results]

And now if I run this query

```
SELECT * FROM `barcode_log` WHERE barcode_log.assign_time BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND CURRENT_DATE;
```

I get this result

[image: query result]

But it should return all the rows as all the data is within this month only. And `assign_time` field is stored as `datetime`. Any idea what i am doing wrong??

Comment: Is `BETWEEN` inclusive? Because this might work tomorrow. You are comparing dates, not times.

Comment: Perhaps taking just the date of `barcode_log.assign_time` might work: `WHERE DATE(barcode_log.assign_time) BETWEEN ...`

Comment: @BartFriederichs , yes between is inclusive.

Comment: @BartFriederichs, Yes, that works too. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are ignoring the `time` part (`hh:mm:ss`).

If the end day is set to the end timestamp of the current date then you can get the data of current day's too.

<sub>BETWEEN is inclusive</sub>

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    `barcode_log`
WHERE
    barcode_log.assign_time BETWEEN DATE_SUB(
        CURRENT_DATE,
        INTERVAL 30 DAY
    )
AND TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(CURDATE(),' ','23:59:59'));
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked. Didn't know about BETWEEN being inclusive.

Comment: `SELECT 2 BETWEEN 2 AND 3;` - This simplest example shows `between`'s inclusive behavior very well.

Answer (score 2):

While the accepted answer works, there is a simpler solution. Just take the date part of the datetime column:

```
SELECT 
     * 
FROM 
    `barcode_log` 
WHERE 
    DATE(barcode_log.assign_time) 
    BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND CURRENT_DATE;
```

Comment: Nice way to handle this through the date part. But one potential problem is index on `assign_time` field cannot be used (if any).

Answer (score 0):

There is another way around: CAST() on `barcode_log.assign_time` field.

```
SELECT * 
FROM `barcode_log` 
WHERE CAST(barcode_log.assign_time AS DATE)
BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND CURRENT_DATE;
```

This excludes time from comparison and works fine for your purpose.